# Unity Procedural Game Optimization

Tags: unity, c#

I am currently developing a 3d dungeon crawler which implements a procedural dungeon generation system which works perfectly fine. I am currently trying to optimize the game to the best of my abiltiy. These are some of the methods I've implemented so far please let me know if you have any other performance tips and tricks:

- Static Batching for all the generated rooms and all the generated decor using StaticBatchingUtility.Combine()
- Occlusion Culling (though I am not sure if it works correctly because the dungeon is generated at runtime, maybe you have any suggestions on how to correctly implement it)
- LOD Groups for each room prefab and decor object
- Custom mesh colliders made in blender that have a low poly count for each object
- Hard Shadows on all point lights, that are realtime, and currently using defferd lighting on the project settings. And the lights light up as you enter the room.
- Quality settings are kept as default
- Currently there is only a fps controller and the dungeon generator so there aren't any other scripts that might be impacting performance
- No effects or particle systems in the scene
- All objects use the same material and is not cloned when the prefab is instantiated.

---

If you have any other suggentions I would really appreciate it. If you need any more info please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

[image: Currently getting around 160 - 180 fps,]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The profiling results there seem to indicate you're running well above 90 FPS already. So it's unclear to me what problem or bottleneck our answers should focus on improving. Can you elaborate on one specific issue you're unsatisfied with in your game's current performance profile?

Comment: Yes i get around 166 fps when i place objects in 1 room, however i will have hundreds of objects on each level plus enemies and i want to optimize it early on so i don't run into the same problem later.

Comment: Try placing hundreds of objects now and measure what that does. They don't have to be the right objects in the right arrangements — just anything "close enough" to get an estimate of load. That will give you a good ballpark of the performance you can expect, and help you identify where your bottlenecks are. Then you can ask a focused question about the specific bottleneck you've identified — or, if you don't find one and your performance is adequate in that test, then you can save time and worry and just proceed with your development as-is, keeping an eye out for new problems as you go.